# gsutil ls: AccessDeniedException: 403 This service is not available from your region

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After my VPS provider moved their servers to a new location, I get `AccessDeniedException: 403 This service is not available from your region` error for every `gsutil` request.

New server IP where `gsutil` doesn't work is `51.254.184.21`, previously it was `88.198.255.218`, and that one worked ok.

I found [related issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=197) from bigquery where the similar error was caused by incorrect mapping of IP addresses on Google's side.

I am asking here on SO, because that's where Google [routes their support page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support).

Comment: Where is your server located?

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior?

Comment: George: Yes :(( `gsutil ls` `AccessDeniedException: 403 This service is not available from your region`